# How to save a model record as a template for reuse later

Tags: django, django-models

I have a basic blog app that has a Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(), null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    template_specific_entry = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I need users to be able to create a Post template with `template_specific_entry` field values, and then other users to use these templates to create **new** post records, updating `title` and `content` but not `template_specific_entry`.

See the example use case below:

[image]

I would like to retain the original Post templates in their original form, so multiple versions of that template can be used.
My question is: what's the most efficient way to go about creating this structure?

- Should I create two models, `PostTemplate` and `Post` and somehow link the `template_specific_values` between them?
- Since this is 'row level' functionality, is it better to do this via model methods, so templates and posts are stored in the same model? E.g. `def createTemplate(self):` and `def createPost(self):` referencing the same model?

In each case how would I actually implement this?

Comment: Your drawing makes it clear that `PostTemplate` and `Post` are different models. You should remove the `template_specific_entry` field from `Post` and instead, use a `ForeignKey` to `PostTemplate` where that field is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your drawing is a very good way to understand the problem you're trying to solve. And in fact, it's also clearly showing how your models should be constructed. You have **templates** and **posts** and each **post** needs to be linked to *one and only one* template.

You can almost see your drawing as the blueprint for your models:

- `PostTemplate` has a `ForeignKey` to `User` (since there's an author, in your example "Author1") and has some specific characteristics (`template_specific_values` although I would try to name this field differently). Note that you use *plural* here, so I'm wondering if this should be a `CharField` and not something else, like an `ArrayField`.
- `Post` has a `ForeignKey` to `User` (the author) and to `PostTemplate`, so that one template can "have" many posts, but each posts only one template.

When the user has selected a template, and then writes the post, the fk of the post gets set to the chosen template.

Comment: Thanks, so where `template_specific_values` should be the only editable field in the `Post` model (it instead should inherit values for other fields from the `PostTemplate` model), should I restrict this editing in the UI or is it better to programmatically do it in the model somehow? I understood it's always better to separate business logic from the frontend?

Comment: You shouldn't have the `template_specific_values` field **at all** in your `Post` model, because all the template specific stuff will be in the `PostTemplate` model. You'll be able to get the values with `post.post_template.some_field`.